# How can I cut my own hair to different lengths?

Tags: personal-care, hair

I have used a pair of clippers to cut my own hair.

This is great for a "buzz" look for uniformly short hair. I can then trim around my ears but if I want it to be longer it's difficult. I've never found a way to properly blend my hair as to leave the top at a longer length, etc.

How can I cut my own hair to different lengths?

Answer (score 6):

The [flowbee](http://www.flowbee.com/) is a nice product for this situation.

However, not all "made for tv" items work as expected. I have found that using my fingers + the guard that comes with the clippers gives a nice inch and a half length to the top of my head.

There are numerous guard lengths available for many hair clipper brands, usually numbered 1-4 (4 being the longest). Try a "number 4" guard and use a "scissors" pinching motion on your hair, running the clippers with the guard attached across your fingers. The combination of the guard and the fingers may be enough to give you the length you want.

you can also try to mimic the hair salon method of using a comb, but this may take a steady hand to hold the hair up away from your scalp, and then trim along the comb. I like the finger method myself because I can safely rest my hand on my head and know it isn't moving around.

Comment: I guess it depends on the style you are looking for and it highly depends on if your "hair-base" is short or long. 
There are tools such as creaclip https://creaproducts.com/ that can help with this.
Creaclip works on both short and long hair, for some styles you can do use it on your own, and for other styles you may need the help of a second person.
There are several tutorials on Youtube and on the product website that you can check to understand how it works, it's basically a plastic tool that can be used as an aid to have an even haircut.